# My daemon code is executing perfectly in the terminal but the log file is not getting created

Tags: c, ubuntu-12.04, daemon

The pid of the process is getting displayed in the terminal but log file is not getting created in the root directory. 
Please go through this code and tell me whats missing.

Output on terminal:

```
process_id of child process 5611
```

Source is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *fp= NULL;
    pid_t process_id = 0;
    pid_t sid = 0;
    int fd,wd,i=0,len=0;
    char pathname[100],buf[1024];
    process_id = fork();
    if (process_id < 0)
    {
        printf("fork failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (process_id > 0)
    {
        printf("process_id of child process %d \n", process_id);
        // return success in exit status
        exit(0);
    }
    umask(0);
    sid = setsid();
    if(sid < 0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    chdir("/");
    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDERR_FILENO);
    fp = fopen ("log.txt", "w+");
    fprintf(fp, "Logging info...\n");
    fflush(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    sleep(1);
    struct inotify_event *event;

    fd=inotify_init();
    wd=inotify_add_watch(fd,"/osa",IN_ALL_EVENTS);
    while(1)
    {
        i=0;
        len=read(fd,buf,1024);
        fp = fopen ("log.txt", "w+");
        fflush(fp);
        while(i<len)
        {
            event=(struct inotify_event *) & buf[i];
            if(event->mask & IN_OPEN)
            {
                fprintf(fp,"%s:was opened\n",event->name);
            }

            if(event->mask & IN_MODIFY)
            {
                fprintf(fp,"%s:file is modified",event->name);

            }
            if(event->mask & IN_DELETE)
            {
                fprintf(fp,"%s:was deleted\n",event->name);
            }
            i+=sizeof(struct inotify_event)+event->len;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The log file is getting created. You need to run the code as root because the log file is opened in '/' directory usually accessible only to root.

Comment: Then you should check manually if you are able to create any file in that folder e.g. 'touch /<file>'

Answer (score 0):

As [Henry Spencer once put it](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html):

> If a function be advertised to return an error code in the event of
>   difficulties, thou shalt check for that code, yea, even though the
>   checks triple the size of thy code and produce aches in thy typing
>   fingers, for if thou thinkest ``it cannot happen to me'', the gods
>   shall surely punish thee for thy arrogance.

```
fp = fopen ("log.txt", "w+");
fprintf(fp, "Logging info...\n");
```

You're using `fp` without checking to see if `fopen()` actually returned a valid pointer.
If `fopen()` returns a null pointer, you can check the value of `errno` to see what went wrong.